# How to correctly track the analytics when using iframe

Tags: google-analytics, asp.net, analytics

In our main aspx page we have this analytics code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1301114-2']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'florahospitality.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(function() {   
  var pageTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();   
  var iframe = document.getElementById('reservationFrame');   
  iframe.src = pageTracker._getLinkerUrl('https://reservations.synxis.com/xbe/rez.aspx?Hotel=15159&template=flex&shell=flex&Chain=5375&locale=en&arrive=11/12/2012&depart=11/13/2012&adult=2&child=0&rooms=1&start=availresults&iata=&promo=&group='); });

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Then inside this aspx page is an iframe. Inside the iframe we setup this analytics code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1301114-2']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'reservations.synxis.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'AvailabilityResults']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

The problem is I see to pageview when I go to find the AvailabilityResults page. The first one is a direct traffic and the other one is a cpc.

How come that they have different source? I was expecting that both of them is using a direct traffic.

Comment: Do you have any campaigns setup? Any custom tracking on URL's such as utm_source? How about Goals and funnel paths?

Answer (score 1):

The iframe page loads after the main page has rendered the iframe element. So the flow would be -

1. Main Page is requested
2. Main page is being rendered and loaded
3. Iframe Page is requested from within the main page
4. Iframe page is being rendered and loaded

This will mean that the iframe page will always show up as a Direct traffic. The Main page would show differing sources.